# Netty Client not reading the Messages from server continuously. Need help in writing the server code that responds the client continuously

Tags: java, netty

/*Netty Client not reading the Messages from server continuously. Need help in writing the server code that responds the client continuously.
what I am doing is I have an API, which writes to multiple ports using DataOutputStreamReader and read using  DataInputStreamReader.
I have created a server program using netty that listens and responds.

Issue I am facing:
The server is reading all the messages from the client(API), but it is not responding continuously.

I have attached my server code along with this. */

```
**Server Program**

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.util.SelfSignedCertificate;

    /**
     * * Echoes back any received data from a client.
     */
    public final class EchoServer {

        static final boolean SSL = System.getProperty("ssl") != null;
        static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", 
        "4660"));

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            // Configure SSL.
            final SslContext sslCtx;
            if (SSL) {
                SelfSignedCertificate ssc = new SelfSignedCertificate();
                // sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(ssc.certificate(),
                // ssc.privateKey()).build();
            } else {
                sslCtx = null;
            }

            EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
            try {
                ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();


           b.group(group).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).localAddress(new 
           InetSocketAddress(4660))
                        .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                            @Override
                            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws 
            Exception {
                                System.out.println("New client connected: " + 
            ch.localAddress());
                                ch.pipeline().addLast(new ServerHandler());
                            }
                        });
                ChannelFuture f = b.bind().sync();
                f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
            } finally {
                group.shutdownGracefully();
            }
        }
    }

    **
    Server Handler Program**

    import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
    import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler.Sharable;
    import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
    import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
    import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;

    @Sharable
    public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
            ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
            System.out.println("Server received: " +           
            in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
            ctx.write(in);
            ctx.flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) 
        {
            cause.printStackTrace();
            ctx.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide some logs as to what server is receiving etc. you can add LoggingHandler class to the server bootstrap which will help you in debugging.